# Service that cant detect Wi-Fi

Tags: java, android, service, wifimanager

I am developing an application which can with predefined time(using alarm manger) search for a certain Wi-Fi SSID and silence the phone if found. I wanted my application to be able to run in the background so I made service class for the Wi-Fi searches. also, I made a class that can detect if the specific Wi-Fi is found(in range). I put the Wi-Fi detecord class inside the service class.

the problem:

the services works fine when the application is in the background running ( it searches and detects Wi-Fi successfully) but when I close the application the service works(service is started) but the Wi-Fi detector class cant detect any Wi-Fi's it is as if there is no Wi-Fi's are in range. 
I don't know why  this problem occurs, I hope someone cant help me.

here is the code for my service:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Msi on 1/6/2018.
 */

public class MyService extends Service{
    AudioManager audio;
    String wifis[];
    WifiManager mainWifiObj;
    WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
    String accesspoint = "Silent_Area";
    public boolean founded = false;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {//this is invoked first
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this,"serivce is created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {//work is done here
        mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
        audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        Toast.makeText(this,"serivce is started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(!mainWifiObj.isWifiEnabled()){
            mainWifiObj.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
        System.out.println("-=--=-=RECIEVED Silencer-=--=-=");
        final int[] duration = {0};
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (duration[0] < 15 * 60 * 1000) {
                    while (duration[0] < 7 * 60 * 1000){
                        System.out.println("thread Searches every 5 sec");
                        mainWifiObj.startScan();
                        if (founded == true) {
                            System.out.println("found");
                            audio.setRingerMode(1);
                        }
                        if (founded == false) {
                            System.out.println("didnt find");
                            audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                        }
                        System.out.println("hello keep searching ");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000 * 5);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        duration[0] += 5 * 1000;
                    }
                    System.out.println("thread searches every 30 sec");
                    mainWifiObj.startScan();
                    if (founded == true) {
                        System.out.println("found");
                        audio.setRingerMode(1);
                    }
                    if (founded == false) {
                        System.out.println("didnt find");
                        audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                    }
                    System.out.println("hello keep searching ");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000 * 30);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    duration[0] += 30 * 1000;
                }
                System.out.println("15 min has passed");
                stopSelf();
            }
        });

        thread.start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {//to destroy
        Toast.makeText(this,"serivce is stopped",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onDestroy();
        stopSelf();
    }


    public class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
            wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
                wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
            }
            String filtered[] = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
            int counter = 0;
            final AudioManager manual = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            for (String eachWifi : wifis) {
                String[] temp = eachWifi.split(",");
                filtered[counter] = temp[0].substring(5).trim();
                counter++;
                System.out.println(/*temp[0].substring(5).trim()*/temp[0]+temp[1]+temp[2]+temp[3]+temp[4]+temp[5]);

                if (accesspoint.equals(temp[0].substring(5).trim())) {
                    System.out.println("== Founded ==");
                    founded = true;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    founded=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you requesting the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions in your app?

Comment: Yes. I use the location for time calculations in the main activity.

Comment: @DanielNugent Thank you for your reply. And Yes. I use the location for time calculations in the main activity.

Answer (score -1):

Try extending IntentService instead of Service or creating a ServiceHandler

Examples of both are in the API Guide:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Same thing happens with IntentService. but thank you!